# how to fix this issue? undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native

where i should add navigation?
in function Get Header & Render item is not working, and cannot move to next screen, in stack navigator everything ok, problem as i think in flat list,   have to kind errors

how to fix this issue? undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

or

Cant Find variable : navigation

import React from "react";
import {
View,
Text,
FlatList,
StyleSheet
} from "react-native";

```
const DATA = [
    { id: '1', day: '28' },
    { id: '1', day: '28' },
    { id: '1', day: '28' },
    { id: '1', day: '28' },
    { id: '1', day: '28' },
    { id: '1', day: '28' },
    { id: '1', day: '28' },
];

const renderItem = ( { item, navigation } ) => (
    <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('anotherScreen')}>
        <View >
            <View >
                <View ><Item day={item.day} /></View>   
            </View>           
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const getHeader = ( {navigation} ) => {
    return (
        <View >           
            <View >                
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('anotherScreen')}>                   
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>);
};

const Item = ({ day}) => (
    <View style={styles.itemst} >
        <Text>
            {day}            
        </Text>
    </View>
);

const App = (  ) => {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            ListHeaderComponent={getHeader}       
        />
    )
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is passed as prop to components that are part to your navigation stack,

so if `App` is part of the navigation stack you do:

`const App = ( {navigation} ) => {`

and you can access it inside this component so you have to put you renderItem inside the comp App.

Comment: If you want us to help, you are going to need to share more than you have. Add a link to your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using react navigation v5? If so, there is also the hook [`useNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) you can use if you need to get access to a the navigation object outside of the navigator's linked screens. Another option is to pass your navigation object down to your header as a prop.

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to add to github - i have try but finali cannot. I can explain that code this is only one page. One single Button is in header of Flatlist